# Backward Euler method problem

Tags: numerical-methods

- Let $\operatorname{g}\left(x,t\right)=\alpha t + x$ and
  $\alpha < 0$ is a parameter s.t. $\left\vert\alpha\right\vert$ is large.
- To numerically solve the equation $Y'= \operatorname{g}\left(x,Y\right)$, the *Backward Euler Method* is used.
- Find how small $\omega$ should be so the iteration
  $$
  y_{m + 1}^{\left(i + 1\right)} =
  y_{m} + \omega\operatorname{g}\left(\,{x_{m + 1},y_{m + 1}^{\left(i\right)}}\,\right),\quad i = 0,1,2,\ldots
  $$
  will converge to $y_{m + 1}$.

The first thought I got to solve this problem is to use the error formula, but I'm not sure how to continue from there.

Comment: You have a fixed-point iteration. Apply convergence criteria for these.

Comment: I'm not sure what the convergence criteria are. The only thing I see in my textbook is that if $ \left| h \cdot \frac{\partial f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})}{\partial z}\right| <1$ then the error will converge to $0$ as long as the initial guess $y_{n+1}^{(0)}$ is good enough

Comment: So does it converge when $\left| \omega \alpha \right|<1$? Which implies $\frac{-1}{\alpha}<\omega < \frac{1}{\alpha}$

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Usually you want to integrate forwards, so $0<ω$.